# Unable to add data and sort array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have created a function to add data to my array, and it populates the array tableData as a 2-d array, with values taken from rows and cells of the web table body. I looped through with a for loop and was able to set all the variables in the array, but when I call my function to sort, it says there is an error.
I need to sort the tableData array using my dataSort2D() function.

This is what I have so far:

```
function defineDataArray() 
{
  var tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table.sortable tbody tr");

  for(var i = 0; i<tableRows.length; i++)
  {
    var rowCells = tableRows[i].children;
    var rowValues = new Array(rowCells.length);
    for(var j = 0; j<rowCells.length; j++)
    {
        rowValues[j] = rowCells[j].textContent;
    }
    tableData[i] = rowValues;
  }
  tableData.sort(dataSort2D);
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with sample data of `tableData` , expected output and sort method `dataSort2D`?

Comment: Do you have an html code to share?

Comment: The code we need to see is where you define `tableData` and `dataSort2D`.  It would also be helpful to see the error message your receive.